# Having trouble getting jQuery "not" method and selector working on body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, negation

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why this is not working as expected.

I simply am trying to target the `body` element, but *only* if does *not* contain the `.logged-in` class, but with the code below I get a log to the console whether the class exists or not.

```
if ($('body:not(.logged-in)')) {
    console.log('Hi!');
}
```

...or...

```
if ($('body').not('.logged-in')) {
    console.log('Hi!');
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those selectors actually skip (remove from the whole selected elements) the elements with class `logged-in`.

I recommend you to use the attribute `length` in order to check the existence of an element.

```
if ($('body').find('.logged-in').length) { 
    console.log('Exists!');
}
```

Comment: Ahhh.... yeah I see what you mean, I knew I had to be doing something stupid. So it basically is selecting the element (doing it's job) and hence is always returning true.

Comment: @Brett this `$('body:not(.logged-in)')` is returning something, and for js engine is a truthy (`true`) value.  So, always the condition is `true`.